# Carrot2 license for commercial project without website&documentation

Tags: licensing, cluster-analysis, carrot2

According to carrot2 FAQ we should acknowledge project users about using Carrot2.

> Can I use Carrot2 in a commercial project? Yes. The only requirement
>   is that you properly acknowledge the use of Carrot2 (on the project's
>   website and documentation) and let us know about your project. Please
>   also remember to read the license.

But we don't have and site or documentation because we are building closed project.
How can we integrate carrot2 in these circumstances?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've revised the text on the license and FAQ pages to make the acknowledgment optional, but you still need to include Carrot2 license file in your binary distribution. A common practice is to put the license file next to the relevant JAR file.